# Two Tables Together SQL DB (Join?)

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one called users which consists of names & cities, the other table is called info and consists of search_terms.
How could I find out the names and cities for people who search_terms equal "dog"?
This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
select name,city,search_terms from users join info where search_terms ="dog";
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to read [mcve]. When joining two tables, you need to give some columns to join on otherwise it results in cross join which might not be helpful and will get you incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need `join` conditions.  On top of that, you might want `like` instead of `=`:

```
select name, city, search_terms
from users join
     info
     on ???
where search_terms like '%dog%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the following, but now it doesn't output anything.  Any idea why?  select name, city, search_terms from users join info on users. search_terms = info.search_terms where search_terms like "%dog%"

Comment: Take out the WHERE clause to start with and see if you get any data back.  If you don’t, the data in those two columns don’t match at all and there is an issue.